# lf becoming fl and if becoming fi

Tags: fonts

I'm creating a glossary between English and Arabic words.

```
\newglossaryentry{glos:halfsp}{name=Half-Spaces,text={\myLR{$Half$-Spaces}},description={أنصاف الفضاء}}
```

is giving Hafl-Spaces in the pdf file.

In the preamble, I am using

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[locale=morocco]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=1]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Amiri}
```

As I am writing a book in Arabic.

I have tried many things without solutions.
Any help?

As a sample:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{\hfill}

\makeglossaries


\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[locale=morocco]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=1]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Amiri}


\newglossaryentry{glos:halfpln}{name=Half-Plane,text={\LR{Half-Plane}},description={نصف المستوى}}

\begin{document}

\gls{glos:halfpln}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always on this site please post a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. That makes it a lot easier to help

Comment: You shouldn't write english text with `Script=Arabic`.

Comment: I have changed 
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=1]{Amiri}
to
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=1]{Arial}
still the same problem

Comment: If you want to avoid writing out language tags, `babel` lets you load a language with the `onchar=` option, which switches the language whenever you switch scripts.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you aren’t selecting the English language, so you’re still loading Amiri with the `Script=Arabic` option.  As you note in your self-answer, explicit language tagging solves this problem.  You could write `\textenglish{half-plane}` as shorthand.

If you want the document to change languages automatically whenever you change script, `babel` supports that.  This template compiles with LuaLaTeX from 2020 or later:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\tracinglostchars=2

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{\hfill}

\makeglossaries

% Requires LuaHBTeX, or LuaLaTeX from 2020 or later.
\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=sectioning]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\babelprovide[import=ar-MA, main, onchar=ids fonts]{arabic}
\babelprovide[onchar=ids fonts]{english}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX, Renderer=HarfBuzz}

\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale=1.0, Ligatures=Common, Script=Default, Language=Default]{Libertinus Serif}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}
          {Amiri}
\babelfont{sf}
          [Ligatures=Common, Script=Default, Language=Default]{Libertinus Sans}
\babelfont[arabic]{sf}
          [Language=Default]{Noto Sans Arabic}
\babelfont{tt}
          [Script=Default, Language=Default]{Libertinus Mono}
\babelfont[arabic]{tt}
          {ALM Fixed}

\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\babeltags{english=english}
\babeltags{Arabic=arabic}

\newglossaryentry{glos:halfpln}{name=Half-Plane,text={Half-Plane},description={نصف المستوى}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}

\gls{glos:halfpln}
\printglossaries

للُّغَة العَرَبِيّة هي أكثر اللغات السامية تحدثاً، وإحدى أكثر اللغات انتشاراً في العالم، يتحدثها أكثر من 467 مليون نسمة،

\begin{english}
Arabic (اَلْعَرَبِيَّةُ, al-ʿarabiyyah, [al ʕaraˈbijːa] or عَرَبِيّ‎, ʿarabīy, [ˈʕarabiː]
or [ʕaraˈbij]) is a Semitic language that first emerged in the 1st to 4th
centuries CE.
\end{english}

\end{document}
```

[image: Amiri/Libertinus sample]

A few notes.  I still used a bit of language tagging, which was actually for the IPA characters.  It’s possible to tweak which characters are considered part of which language, but in a more complex document that needs to interpret the same characters multiple ways, you might need to go back to manual tagging.

I selected Khaled Hosny’s Libertinus family (based on Linux Libertine) as the companion English and math fonts for his Amiri.  They are both attractive in themselves and a close match.  I also loaded sans-serif and fixed-width Arabic fonts, which you are free to change.

All documents that use different fonts for different scripts should include the command `\tracinglostchars=2`.  This prints a warning when a character is missing from the current font, instead of logging the error silently.

If you want the numerals and counters to use different forms, you can give options such as `maparabic` and `alph=alphabetic`.

Answer (score 0):

The one solution that I could use (any other sols?)
is to replace
Half-Plane
by
\begin{english}Half-Plane\end{english}
everywhere in the glos file

It is working

Comment: that is what I meant. Your default language is arabic, so without language switch the \arabicfont is used which uses the arabic script.